# Is there a version of kill with feedback?

Tags: linux, kill, ps

Is there a fork or easy mod of the linux `kill` command to provide feedback? I'd like to avoid the cycle of:

```
ps acx | grep rogue_agents
killall rogue_agents # alternately, kill 007
ps acx | grep rogue_agents # did it work?
```

It would be a nice bonus if it upgraded to `kill -9` after some specified period of time.

Comment: pkill might condense the first two lines into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `-w` with `killall` for that:

```
   -w, --wait
          Wait  for  all  killed  processes to die. killall checks 
          once per second if any of the killed processes still exist
          and only returns if none are left.  Note that killall may
          wait forever if  the  signal  was ignored, had no effect,
          or if the process stays in zombie state.
```

So `killall -w rogue_agents` would be enough.

---

**Edit**: For the additional bonus question in your edit...
(about upgrading it to a `kill -9` after some specified period of time)
You could try the following:
(i can't try this myself at the moment because i have no rogue processes :)

```
timeout 8 killall -w rogue_agents
timeout 8 killall -9 -w rogue_agents
```

This will do a `killall` with a wait. The `timeout 8` makes it wait only 8 seconds after which you can do the `killall -9`. I also made that one wait 8 seconds. If the `killall -9` isn't done after 8 seconds there is really something wrong and it would need manual investigation.

You could of course build in a test to only execute the second line if there are still rogue_agents present after the initial `killall` after 8 seconds. And an echo with an error if the process is still active after the second `killall -9`.